# Is it possible,Cognito userpool verification code through ses using lambda trigger and using custom email template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, amazon-ses

Hi Is it possible to send cognito user pool verification code through ses service using lambda trigger and to use custom email template.
Is there any way that I could do it

I need to use email template thtat I uploaded in ses email template.

Can any one provide the lambda function

Answer (score 0):

I agree with https://stackoverflow.com/a/67497492/15909382 and think it is possible.

using SES document here
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-email.html

using Custom Message Lambda Trigger document here
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-message.html

---

And if you want, you might be able to implement it using Custom Email Lambda Trigger.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-email-sender.html

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible.

As pointed out by others, you can configure a Cognito User Pool to send emails using SES as the delivery mechanism, and using the same verified email you use with SES as your "from" address.

But no, there is no way AFAIK to invoke your SES email templates for the Cognito email messages. To customize the email messages sent by Cognito, you can either configure Cognito and write the templates there, or you can hook into the process using e.g. the custom message lambda hook.

Answer (score -1):

Yes there is a message customization option in your user pool settings which allows you to select SES instead of cognito. It also lets you edit the content of the message. If you want to make it even more dynamic, you can use a pre sign up lambda trigger.

Comment: Downvoting. Question specified: "I need to use email template thtat [sic] I uploaded in ses email template." Your answer doesn't provide any details as to whether that's possible, and I believe it is not. Cognito User Pool can be set up to use SES for delivery, and yes you can customize Cognito emails through Cognito regardless, but there's no way to use SES email templates for the Cognito emails AFAIK.